# Custom Web Browser crashed, Python

Tags: python, browser, pyqt5

So, I was building a python web browser with pyqt5, I followed programming hero's tutorial but when I change the link of my webpage, the app just crashes and I have this error:
[image: Code]
Code here:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.showMaximized()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://google.com'))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.navbar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(self.navbar)
        self.btn_back = QAction('Back', self)
        self.btn_back.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        self.navbar.addAction(self.btn_back)
        self.btn_forward = QAction('Forward', self)
        self.btn_forward.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        self.navbar.addAction(self.btn_forward)
        self.btn_reload = QAction('Reload', self)
        self.btn_reload.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        self.navbar.addAction(self.btn_reload)
        self.home = QAction('', self)
        self.home.triggered.connect(self.urlhome)
        self.navbar.addAction(self.home)
        self.bar = QLineEdit()
        self.bar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to)
        self.navbar.addWidget(self.bar)
        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.nurl)
    def urlhome(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://google.com'))
    def navigate_to(self):
        url = self.bar.text()
        self.browser.setUrl(url)
    def nurl(self, q):
        self.bar.setText(q.toString())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setApplicationName('Private browser ^^')
window = Main()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def navigate_to(self):
    url = self.bar.text()
    self.browser.setUrl(url)
```

The only explaination is that `self.bar.text()` returns a `str`, while a different type was expected.

Comment: Thank you, so we should replace `self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(url))`, thank you ^^.